# How to construct a proper command string in bash? Quoting issues, I think

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, expansion

I have a very newbie question, I am sure. I am trying to construct a script to edit the internal EXIF timestamps of a number of JPG photo files, using the commandline exiftool utility. My actual problem comes in constructing the command string.

I need the command executed by the script to appear as follows:

```
exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place -DateTimeOriginal="2015:12:29 08:00:00" filename.jpg
```

The relevant portion of my script is:

```
# compute timestamp
TIMESTAMP="2015:12:29 `printf %02d $HOUR`:`printf %02d $MIN`:`printf %02d $SEC`"
# Set options string for exiftool
EXOPTION='-overwrite_original_in_place -DateTimeOriginal="'$TIMESTAMP'"'
# Execute exiftool on the current file
exiftool $EXOPTION $f
```

However, the **set -x** option in my script shows me that what is being executed is

```
exiftool -overwrite_original_in_place '-DateTimeOriginal="2015:12:29' '08:00:00"' filename.jpg
```

Extra single quote characters are being inserted into the **DateTimeOriginal** option, and I do not understand why or how.

Thanks in advance for any assistance rendered.

JGB

Comment: Using double-quotes rather than single-quotes (and escaping the double-quotes you *need*) is a step in the right direction.

Comment: This problem is answered in great detail here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- short answer: you can't do it with clever quoting, you have to use bash arrays.

Comment: I agree with Thomas Dickey.  String substitution and expansion doesn't occur in strings with single-quotes.  You might need to try something like this, instead: EXOPTION="-overwrite_original_in_place -DateTimeOriginal=\"$TIMESTAMP\""

Answer (score 0):

You should not be afraid what set -x shows you. It just indicates where word boundaries and white spaces are found in it's own way but that is no what your command will be when called.

Nevertheless you should consider writing your expressions a bit simpler for the clear picture. For example:

```
TIMESTAMP=`printf '2015:12:29 %02d:%02d:%02d' $HOUR $MIN $SEC`
EXOPTION="-overwrite_original_in_place -DateTimeOriginal=\"$TIMESTAMP\""
```